# Fake/randomize/delete geolocation in Safari for certain Websites

Tags: macos, safari, proxy, geolocation

I would like Safari on Mac OS X Lion to send correct geo informations to some websites but not to others. Instead sending correct location data I would like it to send either no location data, faked or random coordinates.

Is there something to achieve that? Maybe a Safari extensions or a [Glimmer Blocker](http://glimmerblocker.org/) script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to simulate location on Safari on OS X](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/246590/how-to-simulate-location-on-safari-on-os-x)

Answer (score 1):

I believe Safari will do something like this by default (Mac OS X 10.7.3, Safari 5.2).

If you look in the Privacy pane of Safari’s preferences, there’s a panel:

> Limit website access to location services:
>
> - Prompt for each website once each
> - Prompt for each website one time only
> - Deny without prompting

I believe the first option is the default, so when you visit a page that wants geolocation data in the default setting, you get a panel like this:

[image: A screenshot of benwerd.com/lab/geo.php, with a prompt from Safari asking whether the user wants to allow the page to access their location data. This page is a test of the HTML geolocation API.]

In the default setting, the page will throw up that prompt every time I reload it (so if I click “Allow”, then refresh the page, I get the same prompt).

If I select the second option from above (“prompt for each website one time only”), then Safari will throw up that panel once, then remember your choice forever.

If you want to learn more, Apple has published two support articles on the topic:

- “About Location Services in OS X Lion and Safari 5.1 or later”, http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5009, accessed 9 May 2012.
- “About Location Services in Mac OS X v10.6 and Safari 5.0”, http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4239, accessed 9 May 2012.

Hope this is useful.

---

Addendum: I don’t know of any way to have Safari supply *fake* location data.

Comment: We have come a long way in he last 20 years. back than it was dubious to tell private data on the internet like name and coordinates. now it is suspected, if you take your right of privacy.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to route through a VPN or other proxy in the location you want to "be" in.

Or, use the [Tor browser](https://www.torproject.org) (but it's not Safari).  By default, it routes your traffic through three servers picked at random.  The website will get the location of the third one.  You can reduce the randomness by specifying one or more country codes in a configuration file.

If you like the Tor approach but still want Safari, you can install the full Tor package and have it handle all your traffic—just turn it on when you want the re-routing and turn it off afterward.