# How to simulate location in Safari for macOS?

Tags: macos, safari, geolocation

I am developer and I'm trying to simulate a different location other than my own on Safari on OS X / macOS. How do I do that?

This is not a duplicate of [how might one spoof geographic location on a desktop Mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/73125/how-might-one-spoof-geographic-location-on-a-desktop-mac). That question is about spoofing the location system-wide. I am *not trying to* (and actually don't want to) spoof my location system-wide, I just want to change it for Safari only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how might one spoof geographic location on a desktop Mac](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/73125/how-might-one-spoof-geographic-location-on-a-desktop-mac)

Comment: Related question: [Fake/randomize/delete geolocation in Safari for certain Websites](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/37521/fake-randomize-delete-geolocation-in-safari-for-certain-websites)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In **Safari** it seems that this still **NOT POSSIBLE**.

For **Firefox**, there are several browser extensions, e.g. [Location Guard](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/change-geolocation-locguard/) which does exactly what you want. Or you can change it via the configuration, as described in [this Security Stack Exchange answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/147176/71850).

**Chrome** has this functionality built-in in the Developer Console. Press <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>, go to the Console tab and inside the Console tab to the Sensors tab. There you can enable location simulation and specify the coordinates.

[image]

Comment: It's a shame that we don't have it in developer tools. I'll go on with Firefox.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu (or anyone else who finds this comment later) you can [enable the sensors tab with Cmd-shift-P](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/geolocation).